# Why obtained MachineGuid looks not alike a GUID but like Korean?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, formatting

I created a simple function:

```
std::wstring GetRegKey(const std::string& location, const std::string& name){
    const int valueLength = 10240;

    auto platformFlag = KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
    HKEY key;
    TCHAR value[valueLength];
    DWORD bufLen = valueLength*sizeof(TCHAR);
    long ret;
    ret = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, location.c_str(), 0, KEY_READ | platformFlag, &key);
    if( ret != ERROR_SUCCESS ){
        return std::wstring();
    }
    ret = RegQueryValueExA(key, name.c_str(), NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE) value, &bufLen);
    RegCloseKey(key);
    if ( (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS) || (bufLen > valueLength*sizeof(TCHAR)) ){
        return std::wstring();
    }
   std::wstring stringValue(value, (size_t)bufLen - 1);
    size_t i = stringValue.length();
    while( i > 0 && stringValue[i-1] == '\0' ){
        --i;
    }
    return stringValue;
}
```

And I call it like auto `result = GetRegKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography", "MachineGuid");`

yet string looks like

```
㤴ㄷ㤵戰㌭㉣ⴱ㔴㍥㤭慣ⴹ㍥摢㘵〴㉡ㄵ\0009ca9-e3bd5640a251
```

not like RegEdit

```
4971590b-3c21-45e3-9ca9-e3bd5640a251
```

So I wonder what shall be done to get a correct representation of MachineGuid in C++?

Comment: Seeing "9ca9-e3bd5640a251" is hard to explain.  The "korean" is normal, that's what you get when you use a legacy 8-bit ansi function like RegQueryValueExA().  "10240" is also very mystifying.

Comment: @HansPassant It's uninitialized stack garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RegQueryValueExA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an ANSI wrapper around the Unicode version since Windows NT. When building on a Unicode version of Windows, it not only converts the the `lpValueName` to a `LPCWSTR`, but it will also convert the `lpData` retrieved from the registry to an `LPWSTR` before returning.

MSDN has the following to say:

> If the data has the REG_SZ, REG_MULTI_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ type, and
>   the ANSI version of this function is used (either by explicitly
>   calling RegQueryValueExA or by not defining UNICODE before including
>   the Windows.h file), this function converts the stored Unicode string
>   to an ANSI string before copying it to the buffer pointed to by
>   lpData.

Your problem is that you are populating the `lpData`, which holds `TCHAR`s (`WCHAR` on Unicode versions of Windows) with an ANSI string.

The garbled string that you see is a result of 2 ANSI `char`s being used to populate a single `wchar_t`. That explains the Asian characters. The portion that looks like the end of the GUID is because the print function blew past the terminating `null` since it was only one byte and began printing what is probably a portion of the buffer that was used by `RegQueryValueExA` before converting to ANSI.

To solve the problem, either stick entirely to Unicode, or to ANSI (if you are brave enough to continue using ANSI in the year 2014), or be very careful about your conversions. I would change `GetRegKey` to accept `wstring`s and use `RegQueryValueExW` instead, but that is a matter of preference and what sort of code you plan on using this in.

(Also, I would recommend you have someone review this code since there are a number of oddities in the error checking, and a hard coded buffer size.)